# C Language: convert 3 char string ("123") to %.2f (1.23)

Tags: c, string, pointers, floating-point, double

I need to convert a char * string of 3 characters ("123") to a float with two decimal places(1.23).

Comment: Is this conversion arbitrary? or is it any 3 character string, consisting of 3 numeric digits, will be converted into a floating point number like x.xx?

Comment: StackOverflow is not your research assistant.

Comment: Doesn't have to be three to start, but I am converting a string of either 1,2,3,4, or 5 characters in length into a currency format ($ 1.23)

Comment: I've tried subtracting '0' from the pointer, and then converting that to a float, dividing it by 100, then printf using %.2f

Comment: @user1486548: Can you post the C code?

Comment: @Jack, the atoi() mentioned below worked, but you advised me to use atof().  Why?

Comment: My apologies. I had in mind that you want to convert `1.23` string.

Comment: @Jack Oh, gotcha.  Thanks, anyway!  Bill Nelson's response works fine with my code.

Comment: Note that in C, a string is enclosed within double quotes (i.e., "123",  not '123').  Having more than one character enclosed within single quotes is an ill-formed character literal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use atoi, which will convert ASCII to Integer.  Then convert that int to a float.

```
int num = atoi(string);
float f = num/100.0f;
printf ("%.2f", f);
```

Comment: @Bill Nelson - Prefer `strtol` over `atoi`; prefer `double` to `float`.